# How to add Prototype cell in UITableView in Xcode 10.0

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xib, xcode10

When I am dragging UITableView to xib file it does not show any option to add Prototype Cells.

How can add Prototype cell in UITableView in Xcode 10.0

Comment: Was it working in Xcode 9?

Comment: Can't. You can't add prototype cell to Xib file for any xcode version. In storyboard it's ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't. You can't add prototype cell to Xib file for any xcode version. In storyboard it's ok